# A question about ideals of rings

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

In ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which  polynomial is in the ideal generated by $1+x^2$ and $1+x^3$

$\mathrm{A}. 1+ x^4 \\
\mathrm{B}. x^5+x+1 \\
\mathrm{C}. 1+x^6$

This type of questions confused me a long time, please give me a complete procedure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The ring $Z/2Z$ has two elements, neither of which are an indeterminate $x$. Do you mean "In the ring $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)[x]$"? I guess this makes sense: "OVER the ring $Z/2Z$, which polynomial..."

Answer (score 2):

Just do the algebra. Note that (over our ring)

$(1+x^2)^2=1+x^4$

$(1+x^3)^2=1+x^6$

Thus the polynomials A and C are in the ideal. B can't be in the ideal because there is no way to get $x$ out of combination of your two polynomials.

Comment: There is a typo, $x^6$  should be $x^5$ :)

Comment: Why ? $(x^3)^2=x^6$.

Comment: You should also prove why you can't get B using the given polynomials. You can use the fact that $x^5+x+1-x\cdot(1+x^4)=1$. So if B would be an element of the ideal, then $1$ would also be an element of the ideal.